# Deep copy using spread operator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, deep-copy

While going through ways to copy an array into another i came to across the documentation for the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Deep_copy_an_array) where its mentioned:

> Deep copy an array

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [...arr];
arr2.push(4); // 'arr2' becomes [1,2,3,4]; 'arr' stays unaffected
```

In my [experiments](https://repl.it/Chmn/2) I used this method and tried to copy array1 into array2. When i changed array1 however, array2 was changed as well. If deep copy means the new array is allocated new memory, how's this possible?

Comment: What is expected result? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my end. https://jsfiddle.net/jobsh093/

Comment: MDN is a wiki, [and people are doing bad edits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator$compare?locale=en-US&to=1090661&from=1072838) all the time. There is no deep copying involved here, it's just standard copying.

Answer (score 0):

in your example you did:

```
array1 = [[1,2], [4]];
array2 = [...array1];
array3 = array1.slice();
array4 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1));
array1[0][1] = 3;
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2); // changed array1, changes reflected in array2 deep copy where art' though?
```

Apparently when you did `array1[0][1] = 3;`, the change affected both arrays because the spread operator only copies the references to the elements of the original array.
Doing `array2 = [...array1];` like doing `array2 = [array1[0], array1[1]];`, so the array elements point to the same memory locations.

If you want a deep copy, you need to serialize/deserialize like you did using JSON.stringify.

Comment: does that mean the spread operator doesnt deep copy. Does that mean the documentation is wrong?

Comment: @snow I  cannot tell it wrong. The title may be a little bit misleading and I think more explanations are required

Comment: @snow: Yes, MDN was wrong. Don't trust everything there - it's just a wiki. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @Bergi i see now. Thanks